# One note 2010 crashes and corrupt subpages

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-onenote-2010

Have been noticing a peculiar problem with OneNote 2010, first the one note page starts mysteriously panning the page that I have been currently working on, then it crashes and hence I shut it down, then if I try to re-open OneNote I get these errors:

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

This will only stop if I end the OneNote processes manually or if I restart my computer. After this when I re-open my OneNotes I lose the last 2-3 subpages that I working on, it shows that it has not synced but these are files on my computer and I have chosen for it to just work on this computer, any solutions to this? I'm tired of redoing work over and over again.

Comment: Additional info: I am using the Bamboo Pen and Touch, and have installed the latest drivers for Windows 7 also have installed .netframework 3.5 sp1. Hopefully this has got nothing to do with the Pen tablet